# How to select records that don't contain child records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not quite sure if I'm even asking the question right, but here's basically what I have:

```
#models/chapter.rb
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pages
end
```

and

```
#models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :chapter
end
```

How can I select all chapters that have pages? For example if there's 20 chapters and only 10 of them actually have pages, is there an easy way that I can do something like: `Chapter.where(<where pages exist>)` (with the correct code of course)?

Comment: Consider changing the question title. It sounds like you're asking for the opposite result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An INNER join will ensure you only get Chapters with Pages.

```
Chapter.joins(:pages)
```

You'll get duplicates if a Chapter has more than one associated Page. To remove them, use `uniq` or `distinct`.

**Rails 4**

```
Chapter.joins(:page).distinct
```

**Rails 3**

```
Chapter.joins(:page).uniq
```